# Who can helpme? PANDAS and MySql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I need help. I´m new programming in python.

My code is:

```
import redis
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  user="XXXXXXXXXXX",
  passwd="XXXXXXX"
)
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM XXXXXXXXXXXXXX;", mydb) 
df['AskTop'] = 2
df['BidTop'] = 2
df['Price'] = 2 
df['EMA_Corta'] = 2
df['EMA_Larga'] = 2
df['Señal'] = 2
df['positions'] = 2
df['Señal_Trading'] = 2
df['Precio_transaccion'] = 2
df['Posicion'] = "BUY"
df['Log_Ret'] = 2
df.to_sql(name = 'PEPEPEPEPEPE', con = mydb)
print (df)
```

I should have this data into my database, but I get the following error

> "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement") 
>   pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM
>   sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': Not all parameters were
>   used in the SQL statement

Comment: MySQL? Or SQLite? They are different. Please [edit] your question to make it clear.

Comment: as writer it is MySql

Comment: Looks like a missing param/argument not being passed to `read_sql`.

Comment: I trying to read my DB with Pandas

Comment: Your error message says `FROM sqlite_master`. That is a query for checking whether a particular table exists in sqlite. It won't work in MySQL. Are you porting some code from sqlite to MySQL?

Comment: no, this is all my code... the problem come from when i try save my df into my DB df.to_sql(name = 'PEPEPEPEPEPE', con = mydb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify value by using `df.loc[row,col]`.

> con : sqlalchemy.engine.Engine or sqlite3.Connection [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)  # you got error because of incorrect connection type

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

mydb = create_engine("mysql://xx:xx@localhost/xxxx")

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM test;",con = mydb) 

df.loc[0,'posicion'] = "buy"

print(df) #If empty means you will insert nothing

df.to_sql(name = "test", con = mydb, index=False, if_exists='append')
```